# cgo - How to convert string to C fixed char array

Tags: c, go, type-conversion, cgo

I'm trying to instantiate a C struct inside my Go code.
The struct is defined like this, (in an external library that I cannot modify):

```
typedef struct {
    char field1[256];
} S1
```

In go, I did this:

```
func myfunc(mystr string){
    // We need to convert mystr from string to char array
    cStr := C.CString(mystr)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cStr)

    // Should work now
    s1 := &C.S1{field1: cStr}

    // Do something with s1...
}
```

But it doesn't compile because:

> cannot use cStr (type *C.char) as type [256]C.char in field value

I've tried forcing ([256]C.char)(cStr) but it obviously doesn't work either.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Use something like `copy(sq.fields[:], mystr)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to change your struct's field definition to a char-pointer which is pretty standard for strings in C:

```
typedef struct {
    char *field1;
} S1
```

The more complex solution would be <sup>[1]</sup>:

```
arr := [256]C.char{}

for i := 0; i < len(mystr) && i < 255; i++ { // leave element 256 at zero
    arr[i] = C.char(mystr[i])
}

s1 := &C.S1{field1: arr}
```

<sup>[1]</sup> Code untested, cannot compile on this workstation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot modify the struct. It's from an external library.

Comment: The code you provided works :). Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use the builtin `copy()` function for this.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there aren't any convenience methods for handling `[size]C.char` as a string in Go (I think I saw a proposal to add this at one point though...)

In my code instead of handling it directly, I opted to manually write the string into the struct when needed with some like

```
func strCopy(dest *[maxTextExtent]C.char, src []byte) {
    for i, c := range src {
        dest[i] = C.char(c)
    }
    // This is C, we need to terminate the string!
    dest[len(src)] = 0
}
```

And the way I used to handle it, which is much less safe is

```
s1 := &C.S1{
    field1: *(*[256]C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(cStr)),
}
```

Comment: Hmm I wonder if `dest[len(src)]` is actually needed, since arrays/slices in go are 0'ed.

Comment: @OneOfOne: you could be overwriting an exiting array, and it could have been allocated in C.

Comment: If `src`'s length is greater or equal to `maxTextExtent` your code would <s>write beyond `dest`'s upper boundary</s> panic.

Comment: @tomwilde: I know, but Go would correctly panic here (in c you would absolutely want to check)

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was still thinking C when I wrote that comment. On a different note; strike-through doesn't seem to work in comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's working :). I'd like to accept both answers but I think I'll accept @tomwilde's, as he has less reputation and I used his code in the end.
Thanks again!

Comment: @David23: no problem :), check the latest edit though. I'm not advocating you use it, but you may be interested in how assigning it directly could work.

Comment: @JimB: thanks for that :) I've had tried similar things (which didn't work) but stopped in the end as the more "unsafe" was used, the more unsafe it was getting ;).